# Let $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$ be all positive for all $x\in[0,7]$. If $f^{-1}(x)$ exists then $f^{-1}(5)+4f^{-1}(6)-5f^{-1}(\frac{29}5)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, contest-math, inverse-function

**Question:**

Let $f(x)$ be continuous and twice differentiable function. Let $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$ be all positive for all $x\in[0,7]$. If $f^{-1}(x)$ exists then $f^{-1}(5)+4f^{-1}(6)-5f^{-1}(\frac{29}5)$

- A) is always positive
- B) is always negative
- C) is zero for at least one $x\in(0,7)$
- D) is zero for all $x\in(0,7)$

**My Attempt:**

$f''(x)\gt0\implies f'(x)$ is increasing.

Also, $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$. So, to find $f^{-1}(5)$, I need that $x$ for which $f(x)$ is $5$.

Not able to think anything else.

(This question appeared in a JEE mock exam, held two days ago. Answer given is option B)

Comment: Can you check the question as $C$ and $D$ deal with $x \in (0,7)$ while the quantity given doesn’t depend on $x$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I just checked I have posted the question verbatim.

Comment: This is a weird question, since $f^{-1}(x)$ can exist on the range of $f,$ and still $f^{-1}(5)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews hi. How did you conclude that $f^{-1}(5)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: I didn’t conclude that. I only concluded that nothing in the question ensures that $f^{-1}(5),$ or any other specific value for $f^{-1},$ exists. @aarbee

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you

Answer (score 5):

The function $f$ is *strictly monotonously increasing* $(f'>0)$ and *strictly convex* $(f''>0)$. If $f^{-1}$ exists, it is *strictly monotonously increasing* and *strictly concave*. Hence, \begin{align}\frac15 f^{-1}(5) +\frac{4}{5}f^{-1}(6)<f^{-1}\left(
\frac15 \cdot 5 +\frac{4}{5}\cdot 6\right)=f^{-1}\left(\frac{29}{5}\right). 
\end{align}

Comment: Hi. Are you using Jensen inequality? In any case, I am not getting how you wrote $$\frac15\cdot5+\frac45\cdot6$$ Can you please explain?

Comment: No, there is no need to use Jensen's inequality. A function $g$ is called *strictly concave*, if for all $t, x, y$ we have $g(tx+(1-t) y) >tg(x) +(1-t) g(y) $. Just plug in $t=\frac 15, x=5, y=6$.

Comment: thankyou very much